# Just wondering if there is currently any support for JPQL queries in the OrientDB Java API?

Tags: java, jpql, orientdb

I realize that JPQL is geared for relational databases, just checking if there's some little known support or tool that can make my job a bit easier.  I have some named queries that I otherwise need to convert into OrientDB queries.  I am assuming no. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not supported so far.